# FileHelpers - How to read in ® character?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am reading in a CSV file and everything is working correctly.  All fields are going to the correct places but it is converting ® to �.

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(T));
return engine.ReadStream(new StreamReader(stream)) as T[];
```

Any ideas on how to prevent this from happening?

EDIT:

With the help of spender I got this to work:

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(T), Encoding.UTF8);
return engine.ReadStream(new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) as T[];
```

I had to set the encoding in BOTH places for this to work.  Otherwise I saw weird results.

Comment: What encoding are you using?

Comment: Read "**[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)**" by Joel Spolsky.

Comment: Try using the UTF8 encoding when reading.

Comment: My problem was solved by adding Encoding.UTF8 in new FileHelpserEngine(Encoding.UTF8). I was handling Urdu ( Pakistani Official Lanugae ) (arabic writing). Thanking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the proper encoding on your StreamReader.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456.aspx

Comment: I have been changing the Encoding on the FileHelpers Engine, I will try to change it on the stream now.

Comment: It's a suspiciously named method called `ReadStream` that, in fact, doesn't read the stream.

Comment: @spender that's hilarious and also incredibly sad and frustrating all at the same time!